# How to add Tabs and Line Breaks from Array using file_put_contents

Tags: php, arrays, sqlite, file-put-contents

I am connecting to a SQLite database. I use the following query to get the results:

```
$db = new SQLite3('sshTunnel.sqlite');
$results = $db->query('SELECT * FROM TUNNEL');
```

Now, I want to add tabs and line breaks from the row array using `file_put_contents` in PHP:

```
while ($row = $results->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
{
    file_put_contents($file, $row, FILE_APPEND).PHP_EOL;
}
```

The results are displayed unformatted in one line:

```
TestTestTest   Test   Test   Test
```

I wish to have this structure:

```
Test   Test   Test
Test   Test   Test
```

Where is the mistake?

Comment: Please elaborate on how your data looks like when you pull it.

Comment: Added. Please see above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem. `trim()` made it.

```
while ($row = $results->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
{
    foreach ($row as $value)
    {
        file_put_contents($file, trim($value) . ", ", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    }
    file_put_contents($file, "\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}
```

Comment: probably had extra values in the database, so needed `trim()`, but i like how you put it in one line. god job man!

Comment: also, i'd run a update query on the record set with trim, else it may/might cause formatting errors when you try and display values. never forget Murphy's Law

Comment: Thanks, ditto! :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($results))
{
   foreach($row as $value)
   {
     $value .= '|';//use what ever char you what to append
     file_put_contents($file, $value, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
   }
   file_put_contents($file, '\n', FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}
```

Comment: Almost. It is still in one line with some errors. Result: Test, Test, Test, \nTest     , Test     , Test ...

Comment: Update: The line break works with "\n" instead of '\n'. For every row iteration, there are (I do not know why) 4 more tabs added. So with 2 rows, there are 8 tabs. For 3 rows, there are 12 tabs. WTF? :-)